# Concat rows from the same field, according to coincidence with other table in SQL?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, string-concatenation, cursors

I have a problem trying to upload the field `caracter` from a table `t1`. I want to concat the value from `caracter` if this appears in `frase` from `t2`, with the previous value. For example if a found x, y or z in `caracter` and these values appear in `frase` from `t2`, I'd like to concat x, y and z with the previous value in `caracter`.

t1

[image]

t2

[image]

This should be the result

t1

[image]

I tried with a cursor but it doesn't work because I have a mistake referencing at set, previously I tried with while loop but had the same result.

```
 DECLARE @frase VARCHAR (100)
 DECLARE MICURSOR CURSOR FOR SELECT caracter FROM t1 
 OPEN MICURSOR
 FETCH NEXT FROM MICURSOR 

 WHILE @@fetch_status = 0

 BEGIN

 SELECT t1.caracter FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 
 ON t2.frase LIKE CONCAT('%', t1.caracter,'%')
 UPDATE t1 SET caracter=  'caracter' + '(@frase-1)'

  FETCH NEXT FROM MICURSOR INTO @frase
END
CLOSE MICURSOR
DEALLOCATE MICURSOR
```

Comment: Images of data really don't help us help you. Please take the time to provide tabular formatted `text`, or (even better) DDL and DML statements. Then we can consume that data and help you get the result you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this serves the purpose,You have to utilize lead() aggregate function to fetch next row. You can find complete solution in dbfiddle link with table and records populated to demonstrate how the query works. The solution is for SQLSEVER 2019.
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=71510d727bb04478383887e2e8ab3a52

```
update t1 set t1.caracter = concat(t1.caracter,lg)
from
 (select id_val,ver,caracter,lead(caracter) over (order by id_val) lg from t1) tab,t1
 where lg in (select frase from t2)
 and tab.caracter = t1.caracter;

 delete from t1 where caracter in (select frase from t2);

select * from t1;

id_val  ver caracter
1   abc abc
1   abc 3
1   abc x
1   abc 2
1   abc y
2   def def
2   def 5
2   def y
2   def 9
2   def z
```

The output after script is applied,

```
id_val  ver caracter
1   abc abc
1   abc 3x
1   abc 2y
2   def def
2   def 5y
2   def 9z
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, it worked so well. I added a space in the concat function to make it look like I wanted at this line CONCAT(CARACTER_ANA.CARACTER,' ',lg)